# Container include order making a difference with VS140 toolset but not not VS120

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, std

I have a VS solution (containing a number of projects) which builds find using Visual Studio using the VS120 (Visual studio 2013) toolset.

Now I want to start using some libraries which make use of some C++11 features which weren't fully implemented with the VS120 toolset, so it seems like a good time to switch to VS140.

But when I do I suddenly get a number of errors in compiling std library containers (6478 of them in fact).

I've done some investigating, commenting code out, and so far I found that if I compile one specific source file, the errors happen when compilation reaches

```
#include <queue>
```

Now the above line occurs several includes down, after a number of other includes.

If then put in precisely the same line at the beginning of my source file, before any other includes, it builds without errors.

So it seems that something is being set or changed in one of the other headers which causes the issue... but only with the VS140 tools, not the VS120

before I disappear further down the rabbit hole trying to find what is causing this, I was wondering if anyone had any ideas what it might be?

Edit:

Sorry, I forgot to post examples of the errors.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    166 
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    424 
Error   C2334   unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body  GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    167 
Error   C2334   unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body  GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    426 
Error   C2206   'swap': typedef cannot be used for function definition  GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    180 
Error   C2206   'swap': typedef cannot be used for function definition  GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    442 
Error   C2091   function returns function   GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    74  
Error   C2091   function returns function   GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    103 
Error   C2091   function returns function   GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    166 
Error   C2091   function returns function   GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    333 
Error   C2091   function returns function   GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    376 
Error   C2091   function returns function   GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    424 
Error   C2065   '_Left': undeclared identifier  GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    180 
Error   C2065   '_Right': undeclared identifier GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    180 
Error   C2065   '_Left': undeclared identifier  GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    442 
Error   C2065   '_Right': undeclared identifier GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    442 
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'value'    GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    74  
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'value'    GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    102 
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'value'    GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    333 
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'value'    GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    374 
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier '_Swap_adl'    GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    424 
Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    166 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    166 
Error   C2059   syntax error: '{'   GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    167 
Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    424 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    424 
Error   C2059   syntax error: '{'   GuiDemo-app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\queue    426
```

Comment: What error messages? Post a sample.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to do that when I posted the question, but forgot somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause is a macro in one of the headers before `#include <queue>`, which redefines something that the `<queue>` header uses.

e.g. if you have:

```
#include "some_project_header.h"
#include <queue>
```

and `some_project_header.h` contains:

```
#define emplace 1
// ...
```

Then it would completely break compilation of the `<queue>` header, because when the compiler sees the `std::queue::emplace` member function it would say `1` instead of `emplace` e.g.

```
template<class T, class Container = deque<T>>
class queue {
  // ...
  template <class... Args>
  reference 1(Args&&... args)
    { return c.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
```

If VS120 doesn't implement the `std::queue::emplace` member yet (which was added in C++11) then it wouldn't have that problem.

If my guess is right, something in your header is using a name that it shouldn't be using, and that needs to be fixed.

A quick fix would be to move `#include <queue>` to the top of your file, so it is included before the problem in the other header, but that doesn't really solve the problem, just hides it.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to think why the standard library files might have changed, for some reason I'd completely overlooked the possibility that VS120 might only have implemented some of the C++11 library changes in the same way as it only implemented some of the language changes. What you describe seems to fit in with the errors I'm seeing, which suggest that the syntax has been knocked completely out of wack, as you might see if a macro definition was overriding the source.

Comment: Solved it! It turns out a third party library was using a #define to clobber noexcept so that the same code would build in Visual Studio 2013 and before, and on non VS compilers that supported noexcept (it wasn't implemented in VS prior to VS2015). Since the VS140 toolset libraries use it, things were getting completely messed up. Thanks again for your help, the answer seems fairly obvious in retrospect, but sometimes somebody standing away from the problem can see what really should be obvious to the person who's close up.